# Java working with international files. Encoding stuff

Tags: java, swing, encoding, localization

I'm writing a sample test application of which the main functionality is to modifying some text files (does not matter what kind of modifications). These test files are usually in txt format. The problem is, that these files can contain a text in English, German, Polish, Chinese, Arabic and so on.

My question is, what should I pay attention to in terms of encoding stuff. I would like to ensure, that app works for any characters it comes across.

Could you give me some links which I would find useful referring to these encoding stuff (when reading / writing to files) ?

I'm writing this app in Java.

Comment: Always [prefer Unicode](http://cafe.elharo.com/programming/the-ten-commandments-of-unicode/); I have a blog post on some of the practicalities of [Java character handling here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to ensure, that app works for any characters it comes across.

That's fine, so long as you know the encoding of the file. It's important to note that the *encoding* of the file is very different from the *language* of the text in the file. For example, the exact same characters can be represented in UTF-8 and UTF-16.

It's possible to heuristically *guess* at the encoding of a file, but it would be better (IMO) to either require that all your input files use the same encoding, if you can control that... or allow the user to specify the encoding. If you *can* control the encoding, I'd generally recommend UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

If you can control it, you want UTF-8. But it's not just a switch that you flip - Java likes platform default encoding and ancient 8-bit encodings over UTF-8 almost everywhere.

When do you need to use encoding?

It comes down to any string coming out of memory needing to be encoded (when printing to console, writing to a file or sending a database query for example) and anything coming into memory needing to be decoded (when reading console, file, http request, receiving database results etc for example).

If one doesn't specify encoding in these situations, an encoding is used implicitly. Always. The implicitly chosen encoding is usually not what you want and even changes depending on where your program is ran.

It doesn't help that Java has implicit encoding overloads for almost anything and it always seems to be the easier overload to use.

Comment: I need to use proper encoding each time I read/write a line of file. Program is for editing films subtitles. Despite the fact, that most of lines are in English, some exotic (for instance chineese) strings appear quite often.

Comment: @guitar_freak A subtitle file is usually a plain text file, which means it's in a single character encoding. The encoding does not in that case vary per line, everything is in the single encoding. UTF-8 can handle any language. Problem is, you don't actually control the encoding if your program must edit subtitle files that could originate from anywhere. You must be told the encoding of the file or detect it \([very unreliable if the file is not UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection)\).